# Use of async on successive AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

Question here about use of successive AJAX calls and async. Its a bit messed here because of how the data is set up. I need to return listings, but the sever only returns 10 per query, and the only way to determine the total number of listings is a separate query with the boolean returnTotal as true instead of false. This returns the number of listings only, and not the listing results themselves. However, if I run the calls synchronously, the variable startItem (which increments on each loop to load data starting at the next block of listings) doesn't seem to populate before the next call finishes, and results get duplicated. Any way to avoid running both as async? Apologies if my code is batshit ridiculous, as I'm relatively new to jquery.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:server url here,
            data:"creativeID=test&CompanyId=BHSR&StartItem=0&streetlocation="+choiceTown+"&Location="+sectCode+"&PriceMin="+choiceMin+"&PriceMax="+choiceMax+"&ListingType="+checkRB+"&OpenHouse=false&NewDev=false&AuthenticationId=id&ReturnTotal=true",
            dataType: "html",
            async: false,

            success: function(data) {
                data=convert(data);

                $(data).find('Listing').each(function(){
                    $(this).find('total').each(function(){
                        totalList = $(this).text();
                        totalList = parseInt(totalList);
                        totalPages = totalList/10;
                    });
                }); 
            },
        });

        for (i = 0; i < totalPages; i++){

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:server url here,
                data:"creativeID=test&CompanyId=BHSR&StartItem="+startItem+"&streetlocation="+choiceTown+"&Location="+sectCode+"&PriceMin="+choiceMin+"&PriceMax="+choiceMax+"&ListingType="+checkRB+"&OpenHouse=false&NewDev=false&AuthenticationId=id&ReturnTotal=false",
                dataType: "html",


                success: function(data) {
                    data=convert(data);

                    $(data).find('Listing').each(function(){
                        results_xml.push($(this));
                    });
                    result_index=0;
                    result_image_counter=1;
                    startItem = startItem + 10;
                    popResults();
                },
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you do not increment `startItem` until you receive a response. Your code is probably making multiple requests with `startItem === 1` before the first response is even received, and so you will get some really weird behavior (probably will get duplicate responses, and you will only get the first few pages of data).

Avoid using synchronous calls because they will tie up other resources (like javascript).

In this case if you want to insure that you get the data in order, you can make it a serial chain of AJAX calls.

To get serial behavior and enjoy the benefits of AJAX, instead of using a loop make your callback function do the next AJAX request after incrementing `startItem`.

This is easier if you organize your code into functions. To wit:

```
    function GetData()
    {
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url:server url here,                     
         data:"creativeID=test&CompanyId=BHSR&StartItem="+startItem+"&streetlocation="+choiceTown+"&Location="+sectCode+"&PriceMin="+choiceMin+"&PriceMax="+choiceMax+"&ListingType="+checkRB+"&OpenHouse=false&NewDev=false&AuthenticationId=id&ReturnTotal=false",
         dataType: "html", 
         success: GetData_Callback 
      });
    }    
    function GetData_Callback(data)
    {
      data=convert(data);

      $(data).find('Listing').each(function(){
          results_xml.push($(this));
      });
      result_index=0;
      result_image_counter=1;
      startItem += 10; // increment startItem
      popResults();
      if (startItem / 10 < totalPages)
      {
         GetData(); // get next "page" of data
      }
   }
   var startItem = 1; // global variable will be mutated by GetData_Callback
   GetData(); // get first "page" of data
```

To do this in parallel typically requires management of the parallel responses (you can use semaphores, etc.). For example (psuedo code) you could do something like this:

```
var pages = [];
var totalPages = GetTotalPages(); // request via ajax like you mentioned (function not shown)
var pagesLoaded = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < totalPages; i++)
{
    GetData(pageIdx);
}
function GetData(pageIdx)
{
    $.ajax({ ..., success: function(data){GetData_Callback(pageIdx,data);}});
}
function GetData_Callback(pageIdx, data)
{
    pages[pageIdx] = data; // assign this specific page of data
    pagesLoaded++;
    if (pagesLoaded === totalPages)
    {
        // fully loaded; trigger event or call function to render, etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems valid also, but why do it this way rather than using the a for loop? Will looping the calls not work well with AJAX?

Comment: Additionally, I should note that var results_xml has already been initialized as an empty array. So each time the function runs/loops its pushing data into that array, and then each index is tabbed through 1 by 1. Would your method of managing those responses by page still be required?

Comment: The problem is that you do not increment startItem until you receive a response. You should try to increment it before the request instead, or manage it as I suggested. You should use your browser tools or a HTTP monitoring tool like Fiddler to debug this. Fake example: you could have sent 4 AJAX requests, all with startItem === 1, before you ever increment startItem. You could be getting something like this: GET(startItem===1), GET(startItem===1), GET(startItem===1), GET(startItem===1), RECEIVE(startItem===11), GET(startItem===11), GET(startItem===11), RECEIVE(startItem===21), ... etc...

Answer (score 0):

Do you just mean without the async: false?

```
     $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:server url here,
data:"creativeID=test&CompanyId=BHSR&StartItem=0&streetlocation="+choiceTown+"&Location="+sectCode+"&PriceMin="+choiceMin+"&PriceMax="+choiceMax+"&ListingType="+checkRB+"&OpenHouse=false&NewDev=false&AuthenticationId=id&ReturnTotal=true",
dataType: "html",

success: function(data) {
console.log('test1'); // first response ok
    data=convert(data);

    $(data).find('Listing').each(function(){
        $(this).find('total').each(function(){
            totalList = $(this).text();
            totalList = parseInt(totalList);
            totalPages = totalList/10;
        });
    }); 
    var startItem=0;
console.log(totalPages); // total page should be equal too "loop" logged

    for (i = 0; i < totalPages; i++){
console.log('loop'); // enter the loop

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:server url here,
            data:"creativeID=test&CompanyId=BHSR&StartItem="+startItem+"&streetlocation="+choiceTown+"&Location="+sectCode+"&PriceMin="+choiceMin+"&PriceMax="+choiceMax+"&ListingType="+checkRB+"&OpenHouse=false&NewDev=false&AuthenticationId=id&ReturnTotal=false",
            dataType: "html",


            success: function(data) {
 console.log('test2'); // number of test 2 = nb of loop = totalPages

                data=convert(data);

                $(data).find('Listing').each(function(){
                    results_xml.push($(this));
                });
                result_index=0;
                result_image_counter=1;
                startItem = startItem + 10;
                popResults();
            },
        });
    }
},
});
```

Comment: I initially ran it default (asynchronously) and had issues with it not loading all the variables before the second call, that's why I'm now running it synchronously (sorry think I screwed up the order of that above). It works now, but takes a long time to load and has the usual hangups of not permitting click events, etc.

Comment: okay so my code should be ok I guess:
the second call is is only send when he get the response from the first one, so you get the variable.
tell me if it's ok

Comment: Ok I've run your code. Definitely makes sense to run the second call within the callback from the first rather than both as async: false. But its still not incrementing startItem in the second callback. I logged it to console but the initial value still shows as 0 on both loops. Any ideas why?

Comment: maybe because you forget to declare startItem? (code edited)
Tell me

Comment: No I had already initialized it as a global variable. It seems odd that it increments ok in the loop when run synchronously, but not in async.

Comment: in this case the simplest is to check with a few console.log() if it enters the 1st response, 2nd response and the loop. see a quick edit of the code

Comment: Gave this a test. It looks like both requests are firing before either of the callback functions complete. So startItem isn't incremented prior to the second call

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you do not increment startItem until you receive a response. Your code is probably making multiple requests with startItem === 1 before the first response is even received, and so you will get some really weird behavior (probably will get duplicate responses, and you will only get the first few pages of data).

Try this instead. It still uses your loop but it increments `startItem` in the loop before the next request is made to insure that all pages of data are requested.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:server url here,
            data:"creativeID=test&CompanyId=BHSR&StartItem=0&streetlocation="+choiceTown+"&Location="+sectCode+"&PriceMin="+choiceMin+"&PriceMax="+choiceMax+"&ListingType="+checkRB+"&OpenHouse=false&NewDev=false&AuthenticationId=id&ReturnTotal=true",
            dataType: "html",
            async: false,

            success: function(data) {
                data=convert(data);

                $(data).find('Listing').each(function(){
                    $(this).find('total').each(function(){
                        totalList = $(this).text();
                        totalList = parseInt(totalList);
                        totalPages = totalList/10;
                    });
                }); 
            },
        });
        var startItem = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < totalPages; i++){

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:server url here,
                data:"creativeID=test&CompanyId=BHSR&StartItem="+startItem+"&streetlocation="+choiceTown+"&Location="+sectCode+"&PriceMin="+choiceMin+"&PriceMax="+choiceMax+"&ListingType="+checkRB+"&OpenHouse=false&NewDev=false&AuthenticationId=id&ReturnTotal=false",
                dataType: "html",


                success: function(data) {
                    data=convert(data);

                    $(data).find('Listing').each(function(){
                        results_xml.push($(this));
                    });
                    result_index=0;
                    result_image_counter=1;
                    popResults();
                },
            });

            // increment start item BEFORE the next request, not in the response
            startItem += 10; // now the next request will be for 11, 21, 31, 41, etc...
        }
```

You may want to get familiar with your javascript debugger to see the behavior for yourself.

Comment: Agreed on the needing debugger knowledge. I am seeing that its incrementing ok, but I'm getting data in different orders pretty much every time I test it. Doesn't the call wait for the callback to complete before it executes again? I did move the incrementation of startItem to after the call

Comment: If you want to get the data back in a specific order take a look at my alternate answer. It shows two different methods for doing this.  When getting data asynchronously like this there is no guarantee that it will come back in order. You need to either force the order by waiting for first response before making second request, or you need to store each page of data along with an index based on the page number. The other answer shows how to do both of these; this answer just fixed the core issue of `startItem` not incrementing correctly.

Comment: Ok starting to get a better handle on this now. I'll take a look